# Deploying ASP.NET MVC4 App to GoDaddy Compiler issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, web-hosting

Have seen several posts about deploying MVC apps to GoDaddy. None of them seem to address the issue we are having.  We have followed the advice about checking runtime versions, IIS pipeline modes, publishing and copy local to true on assemblies so all works on GoDaddy.Com.

The issue we are having is that when we try to visit the site we get a Group Policy exception because ASP.NET runtime is trying to invoke the C# compiler.

> `[Win32Exception (0x80004005): This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator]`

> `[ExternalException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe".........`

We have gone through the publish settings and elected to precompile the site. That didn't fix the issue.  Have looked at the site and there are no CS files deployed. The `Global.asax` file does reference a codebehind file. Since we precompiled the site we tried deleting the `global.asax` file and that doesn't fix the issue either.

Any thoughts would be great.

Comment: If you precompile your views, do you still see this issue? There seem to be a few things that could cause this: 1) Views being compiled, 2) JIT Compilation on server. For both, the answer would be to ensure that your app has permissions for csc.exe (or vice-versa?).

Comment: In the publish settings we chose to precompile. We did change web.config to set to full trust (GoDaddy.com article said that with ASP.NET 4.0/4.5 trust should be set to full).  Since this is GoDaddy.Com environment dont know how we could grant further permissions to allow CSC.EXE to run).

Comment: Please make sure you have given full permission on your site or you may ask Godaddy to give the permission for you. Please also check this documentation http://windows2008hosting.asphostportal.com/post/Cheap-ASPNET-MVC-3-Hosting-ASPHostPortal-How-to-Deploy-an-ASPNET-MVC-3-App-to-Web-Hosting-with-5cbin-Deployment.aspx and hope it will help too!

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 104):

I have struggled with the same problem for months. And finally solved it. In the plesk on godaddy I changed the ASP.Net settings. First changed CAS-trustlevel to Full. Then I changed in the `Web.config` of my project the following:

- Add trust level full to the system.web
- Remove the compilers in the system.codecom

```
 <system.web>
    compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <trust level="Full"/>             <!-- Just add this to the webconfig -->
 </system.web>

 <system.codedom>
              <!-- All is removed between the 2 tags-->
 </system.codedom>
```

and that solved my problem.

Comment: ^^ that is the answer. Set full trust, and remove everything in the `<system.codedom>` node. Your answer is under-voted.

Comment: thank you, I have been searching the solution about 2 days

Comment: Thank you! This is a problem I've run into recently which I haven't seen before. The `trust level="Full"` part I've had to do before, but I would never have thought to delete everything between the `system.codedom` tags.

Comment: Incredible. After spending hours and hours trying to rework my connection string, commenting out those language tags inside `<system.codedom>` solved it for me What a PITA!!!

Comment: I had the same issue with ASP.Net Web API. Thanks a billion! This works.

Comment: logged in just to upvote this answer. Searched for hours and tried everything. Removing the code between <system.codedom> was the key to getting my application to work on GoDaddy.

Answer (score 18):

You have to remove the compilation info from the web config and it will work.

In addition to precompiling (check the box in your publish settings), add the following to your Web.Release.config:

```
<system.web>
  <trust level="Full" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
</system.web>
<system.codedom xdt:Transform="Remove" /> <!-- No compiling on server, GoDaddy blocks it. -->
```

**UPDATE** (1/27/2017):
It appears (at least on my account) that removing system.codedom is no longer required.

Comment: This is a better approach than the higher rated answer involving manually changing the config. Both approaches solve the problem however.

Comment: Spot on! Fixed in a second.

Answer (score 9):

I had same issue on GoDaddy hosting.

To fix it follow these steps.

Step 1: Choose "Precompile during publish" in Web Deploy settings.

Step 2: `<trust level="Full" />` in `<system.web>` in Web.config

Answer (score 5):

I removed the Roslyn nuget package like explained in the link below, but it's a workarround.

> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/442b100a-2b88-4ac4-b655-0c1345791f15/roslyn-cscexe-web-api-2-on-hosting-server?forum=msbuild

This problem happens with a clean mvc 5 web project from visual studio 2015 template.
I contacted the godaddy support, let's see what they do.

Comment: What they did with me is tell me "Sorry, you have the trust level already set to Full so guess you'll need to find another hosting company." WTF am I missing here?

Comment: They said that by phone support?

Comment: Yes. Not in as many words, but that was there message. And they told me if I needed any privileges not supported on that account, then I'll need to find a hosting account with different privileges.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent. I also have same problem. However, my hosting vendor is arvixe.

1. Add >trust level="Full" />" under >system.web> section in Web.config
2. comment out >compilers> section of the >codedom> in Web.config

The problem Fixed!!!

Comment: Allah tera bhalla kre pai.

Comment: Many Thanks. This worked for me after wasting 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

csc.exe compiler error after publish

comment below on web.config

```
<!--<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>-->
```