# ASP .NET MVC 4 This program is blocked by group policy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry for posting this in here. I googled solutions but nothing worked.
I have a Asp .net MVC 4 project which is a scraping project that uses phantomjs. 
Now I deployed it in shared windows plesk hosting. But the error says "This program is blocked by group policy". I suspected phantomjs is being blocked.

I attached a screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35155114/1271037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace, it appears that the error occurs when Selenium attempts to spawn a new process. Most likely spawning a process from a web app is not allowed by the hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Selenium cant attempts to spawn a new process in hosting provider or you should **connect as administrator** :

if you are hosting in a specific domain click application pool->click on your domain(example.net)->advance setting ->Check you identity in process Model:you should login as **administrator User**..

if your website on default application pool you should click on Default Web Site->basic setting ->connect as : **administrator User**

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by two ways.
1 - Add following code in WebConfig
`<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>`

2- Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution in Visual Studio
Find “DotNetCompilerPlatform” and uninstall it

Answer (score 0):

This answer I found on GoDaddy's community forums, but I thought it would be helpful to share in case it solves the issues for other hosting providers. If the post still exists, view it here => https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Web-Hosting/Problem-with-Windows-Web-Hosting-quot-this-program-is-blocked/m-p/14513#M321

From User "mojosound"

> These things need to happen:
>
> 1. Web.config needs to be changed so that <trust level="Full" /> is added in the system.web section.
> 2. Web.config needs to be changed so that the compilers are removed.  The system.codedom needs to be empty.  <system.codedom /> <!-- No
>      compiling on server, GoDaddy blocks it. -->
> 3. The settings in Visual Studio for publishing the website need to be changed to enable precompiling the website.   The root cause of the
>      issue is that GoDaddy does not allow compiling of the website on the
>      server.  This was the permission issue observed above.  Once these
>      were done the site came up fine.

After making these changes to the Web.Config and Publish settings, everything started working in the hosting environment.