# my project says Parser Error, Could not load type 'IntegratedSolution.Global' after deleting global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, owin, host

I have an mvc5 project with web apis, i am trying to use token authentication so it said that i add startup.cs class and remove my global.asax file. i copied my             `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` into my startup file and removed the global.asax file, cleaned and rebuilt the solution. now it is working fine on localhost, but when i upload my bin files to the host (godaddy) it shows that parser error. i tried to remove all bin files from godaddy and reupload them, same error.
here is my new startup.cs class:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(IntegratedSolution.API.Startup))]
namespace IntegratedSolution.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

and i checked the solution explorer, it doesn't have the global file.

Comment: Is biin folder contain any .exe file? Godaddy always make issue of there is .EXE file in bin folder.

Comment: There are 3 exe files in a folder called 'roslyn', but they were already there in the previous (working) project

Comment: Delete them and check is your project working fine? Also check here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638267/deploying-asp-net-mvc4-app-to-godaddy-compiler-issue

Comment: done but did'nt work, also removed the whole roslyn folder as suggested by one of the replies on that link, still same error

Comment: try option explai here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001/could-not-load-type-xxx-global